# How to split a string into array with regex (by commas that are NOT within the brackets)?

Tags: java, regex

I need to split a string into array.

```
String test = "test (18,2,3) ,(,Test (,)), Test";
```

I am expecting to split by commas that are NOT within the brackets. This is what I need

```
 test (18,2,3)
 (,Test (,)) 
 Test
```

I tried

```
          String test = "test (18,2,3) , (,Test (,)) , Test"; 
          String colVals [] = test.split("[^(.*,.*)] | ,");
          System.out.println(colVals[0]);
          System.out.println(colVals[1]);
          System.out.println(colVals[2]);
```

But the result was not what I was expecting

Comment: You're not reliably going to be able to do this with regex - you'll need a bracket counter method.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to use a for loop to go through every character ? I thought regex was the best way

Comment: Basically you need to write a parser which keeps track of the depth of nested parentheses, and only splits on `,` when the depth is 0.

Comment: @remus: You make a confusion between what is called *regular expression* in computer science and what is called *regular expression*, *regex* or what you want, that is a tool for text processing that has more features. This one is able to deal with non-regular languages, so your argument is false. The reason it isn't possible to do it is because java regex has not a recursion or a balancing group feature, not more, not less.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte well said. Deleted that comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you have control over the CSV format; if not, ignore this answer.

You should have a system for escaping literal commas in CSV. Unfortunately there's no single standard for doing this. Some people use backslash-escaping:

```
test (18\,2\,3) ,(\,Test (\,)), Test
```

Others use optional quotation marks:

```
"test (18,2,3) ","(,Test (,))", Test
```

And another option is to use tabs instead of commas, if you know there aren't going to be any literal tabs (or if there are but you change them to `\t`). I'll use `->` to represent a tab character:

```
test (18,2,3) ->(,Test (,))-> Test
```

NB: these are the strings themselves - the string literals will need further escaping: `test = "test (18\\,2\\,3) ,(\\,Test (\\,)), Test"`, `test = "\"test (18,2,3) \",\"(,Test (,))\", Test"` or `test = "test (18,2,3) \t(,Test (,))\t Test"`, respectively.

If you use one of these methods, you'll probably be able to find a library for parsing the CSV. Or if you're using tabs instead of commas, just do what you were doing before but splitting on tabs.

If you've got too much time on your hands you could try writing something to do this yourself. I don't think it can be done in the same way, though - you'd have to write a regex that matches the substrings between the commas (not the commas themselves), then create a java.util.regex.Matcher object, iterate over the string with `matcher.find()`, and unescape any backslashes contained within the matching substrings.